# Given a 4 digit lock, where each digit can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, how can I calculate all combinations that add up to a total of 4?

Tags: javascript, statistics

Given a 4 digit lock, where each digit can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, how can I create an array of all combinations that add up to a total of 4?
For example:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1] is good, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 == 4
[4, 0, 0, 0] is good, 4 + 0 + 0 + 0 == 4
[0, 4, 0, 0] is good, 0 + 4 + 0 + 0 == 4
[0, 3, 1, 0] is good, 0 + 3 + 1 + 0 == 4
[0, 0, 2, 2] is good, 0 + 0 + 2 + 2 == 4
[1, 2, 3, 4] is not, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 != 4
```

One idea was to just brute force loop through all 4 digit numbers (0000, 1000, 0100, 0010, ...), add the digits up and see if they == 4, and if so add that to my list. The issue here is that there would be alot of wasted iterations, since I don't care about any digits >= 5 because those will never == 4.

I've been thinking about this for hours and could use a fresh perspective, thanks!

Comment: In your specifications, you're saying each digit can be 1, 2, 3, or 4. But in your example you're using 0 as well. Is that a mistake?

Comment: you're right, let me update. Digits can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4!

Comment: This might help [Generating all combinations of an array](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array)

Comment: use recursive approach. For example like this: `combination(digits,sum)`  first digit find with loop and rest recursively `for (i=0;i<=sum;i++) combination(digits-1,sum-i)` In lowest layer of recursion (digits=1) add solution to list. It is a bit tricky but doable. You can also google **Integer partition** which is very similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal which uses an iterative recursive style for getting the right length and the wanted sum.

It works for any length, like 7, if wanted and for every sum, if reachable.

```js
function combine(array, length, sum) {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

    function iter(a) {
        var r = this.concat(a);
        if (r.length === length) {
            r.reduce(add) === sum && result.push(r);
            return;
        }
        array.forEach(iter, r);
    }

    var result = [];
    array.forEach(iter, []);
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(combine([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4, 4), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(combine([0, 1, 2, 3], 3, 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't do the work for you but a simple optimisation would be to stop the current iteration soon as the combination is > 4.

Comment: That would help, but then it would also be counting iterations that are < 4 which would also be wasted cycles, right?

Comment: this should be in comment